# How could a local compact star remnant be used for space exploration?

Tags: interstellar-travel, black-hole

If a neutron star or black hole was detected, say, only one parsec from here, would it help space exploration?

Could it be used as a gravity assisted flyby portal for interstellar space flight? I suppose that it depends on its speed relative to us and the star we'd like to travel to. But some star remnants have very high velocities because of their violent formation history. And wouldn't a close binary neutron star would be a gold mine for gravity assists.

Comment: This really is two questions. The first question isn't really for this site. How a neutron star might be used, however, is on topic. In fact, this is just too many questions for one, I suggest you break them out between this site and astronomy.

Comment: I agree, the second question is very interesting but we're really not the right site for the first question.

Comment: LocalFluff, would you consider separating the question about gravitational lensing out and posting that as a question on Astronomy? It would be a good question there and it isn't really our area. Otherwise, i think your edit has improved the question and it should be reopened.